# Why function $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ has a pole at infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis

I've read [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-example-of-a-pole-at-infinity-in-complex-analysis) where it says that the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ has a pole of order $1$ at infinity.

I know that $f$ has a pole at infinity if the function $F(z) := f(\frac{1}{z})$ has a pole at $0$.

But $F(z) = f(\frac{1}{z})=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{z}} = z \implies F(z) $ has a $0$ at $z=0$, so it doesn't have pole at $z=0 \implies f(z)$ don't have pole at infinity. Am I wrong or.. ?

Comment: $z$ has a pole at $\infty$ not $1/z$

Comment: @psl2Z So my affirmation is true? ($z$ has a pole at $\infty$, $1/z$ has a pole at $0$)

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: The moral of the story is: Be skeptical when learning mathematics from random internet posts.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes... that's why I asked this because I can't figure out what that user says..